# XML DTD failling to validate

Tags: xml, validation, exception, dreamweaver, dtd

I have an XML file with an external DTD... here is the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT slideshow (slide+)>
<!ELEMENT slide (image,date,time,narrative*,character*)>
<!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT time (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT narrative (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT character (name,dialogue*)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dialogue (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST dialogue name CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

And here is the head of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE slideshow SYSTEM "slideshow.dtd">
```

The XML validates fine against the DTD, however when I validate the DTD in dreamweaver, it is failing to validate with the following errors:

```
line 1: Expected comment or CDATA[xml] 
line 3: An exception occurred! Type:EmptyStackException, Message:The element stack is empty[xml]
```

I can't see why this is happening, does anyone know?

Comment: Without the rest of the XML, it would be hard to help you

Comment: @Rado the rest of the XML is over 1300 lines. This isn't throwing an error at the way I have structured my XML but the way I have declared the elements in the DTD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with the way the dtd is defined. This validated successfully with Kate's XML Validator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE slideshow SYSTEM "slideshow.dtd">
<slideshow>
  <slide>
    <image>dsds</image>
    <date>dsads</date>
    <time>dsads</time>
    <narrative>fdfd</narrative>
    <narrative>fdfd</narrative>
    <character>
      <name>dasdsa</name>
      <dialogue name="dsds">dsads</dialogue>
    </character>
  </slide>
</slideshow>
```

[edit] i got a hold of a machine with dreamweaver and I believe I found out the problem. When there is no dtd defined, dreamweaver tries to fallback against a known schema and validate the document. The default fallback can be set in edit->preferences->validator and by default it is set to check against HTML 4.0. Since dtd's are not valid XML or HTML files, the validator properly displays errors. I don't think dreamweaver can properly validate dtd's so I suggest you either ignore the errors or use an XML schema instead of dtd's since it is a proper XML document. Your dtd is valid.

Comment: Try validating the physical `slideshow.dtd` file. My XML page validates fine (like yours above and structured the same) it is when I attempt to validate the actual contents of the document type declaration. (I am using dreamweaver's validation)

Comment: @GeorgeReith I don't have dreamweaver so I can't really help you. You could try to include an xmlns declaration and see if that helps. Add `<!ATTLIST slideshow xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>` right after `<!ELEMENT slideshow (slide+)>` in your DTD and see if you get a different error. You may have to add xmlns to every element, but again, I don't use dreamweaver so I have no clue. Good luck!

Comment: @GeorgeReith I believe I found the cause for the error. It doesn't solve your problem, but I think you can just ignore it or move to xsd

Answer (score 0):

This is a little much for a comment, so I'm adding it as an answer.

In the comment to @Rado, you said "it is when I attempt to validate the actual contents of the document type declaration"...does this mean you're trying to validate *only* the doctype declaration? Like this?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE slideshow SYSTEM "slideshow.dtd">
```

If so, that won't work. You have to have a root element and that would explain the "`The element stack is empty`" error.

The validation of your doctype declaration will happen when you validate your XML file. The DTD should also be validated at that time.

If you want to validate your DTD separate from the XML, you will have to validate the DTD file itself. I also don't have Dreamweaver, but your DTD validates fine in [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/).

Comment: I believe the problem is validating the dtd, not the XML.

Comment: I am indeed validating the dtd file itself. I guess this is dreamweaver's shoddy validation tool.